# How to customize the header defined on this .sty file?

Tags: header-footer, packages, beamerposter, posters

I'm trying to make a conference poster using LaTeX and for that I've downloaded one template from the internet. The template I've downloaded is [this one](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/portrait-beamer-poster-template-jacobs-style/fxfzyznxpghw#.VkTObvmrSUk) abd it uses the `beamer` class and the `confposter` theme.

My doubt is that to make the header of the poster we see the commands

```
\title{Title} % Poster title

\author{Author} % Author(s)

\institute{Institute} % Institution(s)
```

With this it generates a header which contains the title, the author and the insitute. Now, I wanted to customize this header, adding more information to it, but I don't know how to do it.

Opening the `beamerconfposter.sty` file that comes with the template I see there is a section

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
 \leavevmode
  \begin{columns}
   \begin{column}{\linewidth}
    \vskip1cm
    \centering
    \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{jblue}\Huge{\textbf{\inserttitle}}\\[0.5ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\Large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}
    \vskip1cm
   \end{column}
   \vspace{1cm}
  \end{columns}
 \vspace{0.5in}
 \hspace{0.5in}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=35in,colsep=0.15cm]{cboxb}\end{beamercolorbox}
 \vspace{0.1in}
}
```

I see the header is being set up here. I tried adding more elements by analogy in there like

```
\usebeamercolor{authorsemail in headline}{\color{fg}\Large{\inserauthorsemail}\\[1ex]}
```

and tried adding to the poster file something like

```
\authorsemail{author@server.com}
```

but this didn't work since the control sequence `\authorsemail` is undefined.

Is there something special with `title`, `author` and `institute` that this works only with them? I read all the files of the template but they are not mentioned in any other place, so they are not defined elsewhere.

So, how can I customize the heading defined on that `.sty` file? What is the right way to customize it?

I believe all comes down to the definition of those `\insertauthor`, `\inserttitle` and `\insertinstitute` commands. But where they are being defined?

**EDIT**: Also there is no maketitle on this one. Indeed after using those commands I pointed out the document starts like this:

```
\begin{document}

\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under blocks
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under highlighted (alert) blocks

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{2ex} % White space under figures
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{2ex} % White space under equations

\begin{frame}[t] % The whole poster is enclosed in one beamer frame

\begin{columns}[t] % The whole poster consists of three major columns, the second of which is split into two columns twice - the [t] option aligns each column's content to the top
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @JohnKormylo. Now, sorry for the silly question (I'm new to creating posters with LaTeX), but on this case there is no \maketitle. I've added one edit talking about this. In this case where is the title being inserted?

Comment: \insertauthor is described in the manual.  Alas, \usebeamercolor is not.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a custom headline with author's email added.  I would rather not install confposter.sty which presumably defines colors jblue and jg.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
 \leavevmode
  \begin{columns}
   \begin{column}{\linewidth}
    \vskip1cm
    \centering
    \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\Huge{\textbf{Title goes here}}\\[0.5ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\Large{Author goes here}\\[0.5ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\Large{email goes here}\\[1ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\large{Institute goes here}\\[1ex]}
    \vskip1cm
   \end{column}
   \vspace{1cm}
  \end{columns}
 \vspace{0.5in}
 \hspace{0.5in}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=35in,colsep=0.15cm]{cboxb}\end{beamercolorbox}
 \vspace{0.1in}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
This page left blank.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: beamer frame]